# PHP - Mysqli Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I go to the website URL I get this "Mysqli Error".  This is the only text that shows up on the page.  I read that it has to do with mysqli() functions.  I have added the or die("Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']) to some of the mysqli() but that hasn't fixed the problem.  This is the code of the only PHP file I have that has these functions:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

class DB_Functions_GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'] = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Mysqli Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']));

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    public function connectDefaultDatabase() {

        $GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'] = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Mysqli Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']));
        return $GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'];
    }

    public function selectDatabase($db) {
        mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], $db);
    }

    public function closeDatabase() {
        mysqli_close($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']);
    }

    public function connectNewDatabase($host, $user, $password, $dbname = "") {
        closeDatabase();

        if ($dbname != "" && $dbname != null) {
            $GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'] = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname) or die("Mysqli Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']));
        } else {$GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'] = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Mysqli Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']));
        }

        return $GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'];
    }
/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
    public function getUserByEmail($email) {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
        return $result;
    }

    public function getUserByName($username) {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        return $result;
    }

    public function getUserById($id) {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Getting all users
     */
    public function getAllUsers() {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "select * FROM gcm_users");
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check user exists or not
     */
    public function checkUserById($id) {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users WHERE gcm_regid = '$id'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function deleteUserById($id) {
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "DELETE FROM gcm_users WHERE gcm_regid = '$id'");
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function storeUser($gcm_regid, $instanceId, $name, $email) {
    echo "$gcm_regid";
        // insert user into database
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "INSERT INTO gcm_users(name, email, gcm_instance_id, gcm_regid, created_at) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$instanceId', '$gcm_regid', NOW())");

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details
            $id = mysqli_insert_id($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']);
            // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection'], "SELECT * FROM gcm_users WHERE id = $id") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli_connection']));
            // return user details
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming this isn't public-facing at this time, set up error_reporting (probably to E_ALL) and set the ini value for "display_errors" to true.  You should get some additional (and more meaningful) feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `mysqli` connection fails, the return value you get back is a boolean `FALSE`, and cannot be used as a parameter for `mysqli_error()`. That's why there's `mysqli_connect_error()`. e.g.

```
$con = mysqli_connect([..snip..]) or die (mysqli_error($con));
```

Think about it. `$con` can only get a value AFTER the entire right-hand side of the operation has completed. But you're trying to USE that `$con` in the right-hand side, which is impossible. PHP cannot/will not time travel. The code should be

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Mistake #2:

You're defining an object. Why are you returning your mysqli handle and saving it as a PHP global variable? That means you can only ever have one DB connection open at a time, because any further instances of your object will simply overwrite/use that same global variable. Why aren't you storing the handle in your object?

```
public function dbconn() {
    $this->dbh = mysqli_connect(...) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
}

public function do_db_stuff()
   mysqli_query($this->dbh, "SELECT blah blah blah");
}
```

Comment: He obviously copied the design from some code that was generated from a `mysql->mysqli` converter. It uses a global variable to emulate the way the `mysql` extension allows the connection to be defaulted.